# Back button is not working when using history.pushState() in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently, I am working on a ReactJs project where I've created infinite scrolling on the basis of scrolling events. My client wanted to have URL changing while scrolling up and down.

For achieving this functionality I've used history.pushState() which updating URL like:- /#/page/1...2...3 up to n.

But the problem is when I am clicking back button from the browser, it is going to the previous state rather than the previous page (as the nature of history.pushState()).

I would appreciate if anyone helps me out to sort it out.

Thanks in advance.

**Here is my code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ComponentView from './view';
import axios from 'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';
import { createAction,ActionNames } from '../../redux/actions/index';
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
/**
 * @name Product Grid Component
 * @type Component
 * @author Inderdeep Singh
 */
class Main extends Component {

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param props
     */
    state = {
        items: [],
        isLoading: true,
        cursor: 0
    }

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.pageSize = 10;
        this.state = {
            data:[],
            link:'',
            loading:true,
            items: [],
            isLoading: false,
            loadAll:false,
            cursor: 0,
            arrSize: 12,
            productsLen:0,
            section:0,
            scrollUp:0,
            url:'',
            sectionSize:'',
            sectionSizeLim:1
        }

        this.handleOnScroll = this.handleOnScroll.bind(this);

    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleOnScroll);


    }

    clickBackButton(){
        const history = createHistory();
                var myarray = [];
                var url = history.location;
                myarray.push(url);


        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
            var hashLocation = location.hash;

            var hashSplit = hashLocation.split("/");

            var hashName = hashSplit[1];



            if (hashName !== '') {
              var hash = window.location.hash;

              if (hash === '') {

                var number= url.hash;
                number= number.split('/');
                this.console.log("nagesh "+number[2]);

              }
            }
          });
    }


    /**
     * Component Did Mount
     */
    componentDidUpdate(props){  
        this.clickBackButton();

    }


    componentDidMount(){
        var url = window.location.href;
        this.setState({url:url})
            if(url.indexOf('#')>-1){
                if(url.indexOf('kategori')>-1){
                    url = url.split('/');
                    var pageNum = url[6];
                    var catName = url[4];
                    var timesRun = 0;
                    var Scrolling = setInterval(function () {
                        timesRun += 1;
                        if(timesRun <= pageNum){
                            window.scrollTo(0, pageNum * 1930);
                            var fact ='/kategori/'+catName+'/#/page/'+timesRun;
                            history.pushState(null,null,fact);
                        }
                        else{
                            clearInterval(Scrolling)
                        }
                    },1000);
                }
                else if(url.indexOf('produkt')>-1){
                    url = url.split('/');
                    var pageNum = url[6];
                    var catName = url[4];
                    var timesRun = 0;
                    var Scrolling = setInterval(function () {
                        timesRun += 1;
                        if(timesRun <= pageNum){
                            window.scrollTo(0, pageNum * 1930);
                            var fact ='/produkt/'+catName+'/#/page/'+timesRun;
                            history.pushState(null,null,fact);
                        }
                        else{
                            clearInterval(Scrolling)
                        }
                    },1000);
                }
                else{
                    url = url.split('#');
                    url = url[1].split('/');
                    url = url[2];
                    var timesRun = 0;
                    var Scrolling = setInterval(function () {
                        timesRun += 1;
                        if(timesRun <= url){
                            window.scrollTo(0, url * 1930);
                            history.pushState(null,null,'/#/page/'+timesRun);
                        }
                        else{
                            clearInterval(Scrolling)
                        }
                    },1000);

                }

                }

        const {emitter} = this.props;
        emitter.addListener("REFRESH_PRODUCTS",(query)=>{               
            this.getProducts(1,query)
        })
        this.setState({data:this.props.data})

        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleOnScroll);
        this.doQuery();


    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
        if(JSON.stringify(this.props.query)!=JSON.stringify(newProps.query)){
            this.getProducts(1,newProps.query)
        }



    }

    doQuery = () => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true, error: undefined })
        axios.post('/getProducts')
            .then((res) => {

                this.setState({

                    productsLen:res.data.results.length,
                    sectionSize:parseInt(res.data.results.length/12)
                });
            })
    }
    handleOnScroll() {
        var self = this;
function callURL(ss){

    var url = window.location.href;
        setTimeout(
            self.setState({
                arrSize: self.state.arrSize + 12,
                isLoading: true
            }), 3000);
        var url = window.location.href;
        if(self.state.sectionSizeLim<=self.state.sectionSize){
            self.setState({
                sectionSizeLim: self.state.sectionSizeLim + 1,
            })
        }
        if (self.state.arrSize <= self.props.product_list.length) {
            var sect = self.state.section;
            if (url.indexOf('#') > -1) {
                url = url.split('#');
                url = url[1].split('/');
                url = url[2];
                if (sect <= url) {
                    sect = sect + 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                sect = sect + 1;
            }
            self.setState({
                isLoading: true,
                section: sect
            })
        }
        else {
            self.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                loadAll: true
            })
        }
        if(ss==0){
            if (self.state.url.indexOf('kategori') > -1) {
                var url = self.state.url.split('/');
                var fact = '/kategori/' + url[4] ;
                // history.pushState(null, null, fact);
                // window.location.hash = fact;
                // window.location.hash = '';
                // window.location.href.split('#')[0];
                window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", fact,"/");
            }
            else if (self.state.url.indexOf('produkt') > -1) {
                var url = self.state.url.split('/');
                var fact = '/produkt/' + url[4] ;
                // history.pushState(null, null, fact);
                // window.location.hash = fact;
                // window.location.hash = '';
                // window.location.href.split('#')[0];
                window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", fact,"/");
            }
            else {
                // history.pushState(null, null, '/');
                // window.location.hash = '';
                window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/");
            }   
        }
        else{
            if (self.state.url.indexOf('kategori') > -1) {
                var url = self.state.url.split('/');
                var fact = '/kategori/' + url[4] + '/page/' + ss;
                // history.pushState(null, null, fact);
                // window.location.hash = fact;
                window.location.hash = '/page/' + ss;

            }
            else if (self.state.url.indexOf('produkt') > -1) {
                var url = self.state.url.split('/');
                var fact = '/produkt/' + url[4] + '/page/' + ss;
                // history.pushState(null, null, fact);
                // window.location.hash = fact;
                window.location.hash = '/page/' + ss;

            }
            else {
                // history.pushState(null, null, '/#/page/' + ss);
                window.location.hash = '/page/' + ss;

            }
        }
}
        var h = ($("html").scrollTop());
        if(h == 0 ){
            callURL(0);
        }
        else if(h >= 1500 && h <= 1930){
            callURL(0); 
        }
        else if (h >= 1930 && h <= 3860) {
            callURL(1)
        }
        else if (h >= 3860 && h <= 5790) {
            callURL(2)
        }
        else if (h >= 5790 && h <= 7720) {
            callURL(3)
        }
        else if (h >= 7720 && h <= 9650) {
            callURL(4)
        }
        else if (h >= 9650 && h <= 11580) {
            callURL(5)
        }
        else if (h >= 11580 && h <= 13510) {
            callURL(6)
        }
        else if (h >= 13510 && h <= 15440) {
            callURL(7)
        }
        else if (h >= 15440 && h <= 17370) {
            callURL(8)
        }
        else if (h >= 17370 && h <= 19300) {
            callURL(9)
        }
        else if (h >= 19300 && h <= 21230) {
            callURL(10)
        }
        else if (h >= 21230 && h <= 23160) {
            callURL(11)
        }
        else if (h >= 23160 && h <= 25090) {
            callURL(12)
        }
        else if (h >= 25090 && h <= 27020) {
            callURL(13)
        }
        else if (h >= 27020 && h <= 28950) {
            callURL(14)
        }
        else if (h >= 28950 && h <= 30880) {
            callURL(15)
        }
        else if (h >= 30880 && h <= 32810) {
            callURL(16)
        }
        else if (h >= 32810 && h <= 34740) {
            callURL(17)
        }
        else if (h >= 34740 && h <= 36670) {
            callURL(18)
        }
        else if (h >= 36670 && h <= 38600) {
            callURL(19)
        }
        else if (h >= 38600 && h <= 40530) {
            callURL(20)
        }
        else if (h >= 40530 && h <= 42460) {
            callURL(21)
        }
        else if (h >= 42460 && h <= 44390) {
            callURL(22)
        }
        else if (h >= 44390 && h <= 46320) {
            callURL(23)
        }
        else if (h >= 46320 && h <= 48250) {
            callURL(24)
        }
        else if (h >= 48250 && h <= 50180) {
            callURL(25)
        }
        else if (h >= 50180 && h <= 52110) {
            callURL(26)
        }
        else if (h >= 52110 && h <= 54040) {
            callURL(27)
        }
        else if (h >= 54040 && h <= 55970) {
            callURL(28)
        }
        else if (h >= 55970 && h <= 57900) {
            callURL(29)
        }
        else if (h >= 57900 && h <= 59830) {
            callURL(30)
        }
        else if (h >= 59830 && h <= 61760) {
            callURL(31)
        }
        else{
        console.log(h);
        }


        var scrollTop = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || document.body.scrollTop;
        var scrollHeight = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollHeight) || document.body.scrollHeight;
        var scrollHeights = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollHeight) || document.body.scrollHeight;
        scrollHeight = scrollHeight - 1000;
        var clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.innerHeight;
        var scrolledToBottom = Math.ceil(scrollTop + clientHeight) >= scrollHeight;
        var scrollToTop = Math.ceil(scrollTop - clientHeight) >= scrollHeight;

    }
    /**
     * Get products
     * @param page
     */
    getProducts(page,customQuery){
        page = page || 1;
        // console.log(page);
        const {getProducts,query} = this.props;
        let obj = {
            ...query,
            ...customQuery,
            query : {
                ...(query || {}).query,
                ...(customQuery || {}).query
            },

            limit : 5000,

            skip : 0
        };
        obj.query = {
            ...obj.query,
            state : 'published'
        }

    }

    /**
     * Render the view
     * @returns {*}
     */
    render() {
        return (ComponentView.bind(this))();
    }
}


function bindAction(dispatch) {
    return {
        getProducts : (data)=>{
            return dispatch(createAction(ActionNames.GET_PRODUCTS,data));
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Map the shared state to properties
 * @param state
 * @returns Object
 */
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    // console.log(state)
    return {
        data: state.products.results || [],
        count : state.products.count,
        hasMore : state.products.hasMore,
        emitter : state.emitter
    };
};


Main.displayName = 'Product Grid';

export default connect(mapStateToProps,bindAction)(Main);
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you try `replaceState()` method instead of `pushState()`.

Check it out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FManipulating_the_browser_history)

Comment: Hi, Akshay Kishore thanks for the reply! sorry to say, but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Hmm try setting your URL like  url/#page1  instead of url/#/page1. That should've worked though. Try adding a state too.

Comment: Akshay Kishore, I was editing code in the wrong place, replaceState() is working but in chrome, it gives me an error and preventing to update URL. The error is "Throttling history state changes to prevent the browser from hanging."

Comment: actually, it is not an error, it is a warning and the issue is only in chrome.

Comment: Yeah! here it is "Throttling history state changes to prevent the browser from hanging."

Comment: Try providing a distinct state object for each page like this  var stateObj = { foo: "page3" };  history.replaceState(stateObj, "page 3", your_url);

Comment: Hi Akshay I've tried the above solution but still getting throttling error and URL is not getting update in chrome :(

Comment: well im all out of ideas, but maybe you can set window.location to a home page or something manually on the popstate event.

Comment: I've tried but it is hard and complex to manage the lots of states. Well, Thank you for your answer... I appreciate :)

Comment: Sorry couldn't help you better, though